# python range weird behavior

Tags: python, range

I need to check a variable, called status, of an object in python. What I am doing is the known:

```
if p.status() in range(21,30):
```

where p is my object. I need to check if this status is between -21 and -29, but it only works if I write the range in positive numbers instead of negative. When I wrote:

```
if p.status() in range(-30,-21):
```

it didn't return anything. (Of course I printed the status of this object and I am sure that this condition exist). Some ideas???

Thanks

Comment: `if p.status() in range(-30,-21):` never returns anything; it's a flow control structure. And as far as I can tell `-3 in range(-5, -1)` gives me `True`. Can you post more details?

Comment: `>>> -29 in range(-30,-21) :: True` `>>> -21 in range(-30,-21) :: False`

Comment: if the bounds are inclusive then you need to write range(-29,-20)

Comment: Just FYI, this is a very inefficient way to perform this test… Better would be `-30 <= p.status() <= -21`.

Comment: `range(-30, -21) = [-30 .. -22]`, try with `range(-29, -20)`

Comment: I think that you need to look at the return value of the callable `p.status()`  BTW: Your range value is not what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget `range`. Chained comparison operators are much more readable.

```
if -29 <= p.status() <= -21:
```

---

By the way, the `stop` argument of `range` is never included in the return value, so for -21 to -29 inlusive, you'd want `range(-29,-20)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract the value from 0 which would produce a positive value which would be in the range:

```
if 0 - p.status() in range(21,30):
```